# How to separate String array data?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

**I have String array:**

```
String[] values  = {"A1","B1","C1","5"};
```

I need to separate digits and cell references like that:

```
String[] b = {"A1","B1","C1"}; 
String[] c = {"5"};
```

Comment: And what have you done fo far ?

Comment: Hint: ignore the array part... given a string, how would you work out whether or not it's a cell reference?

Comment: @ndn The question is tagged C#, so no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using linq it's pretty straightforward (except for the "number only string recognition"). Here it is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    // Input:
    String[] values = { "A1", "B1", "C1", "5" };

    // Results:
    String[] digits = (from x in values where StringContainsNumbersOnly(x) select x).ToArray();
    String[] cellRefs = (from x in values where !digits.Contains(x) select x).ToArray();

}

static bool StringContainsNumbersOnly(string inputString)
{
    return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(inputString, @"^\d+$");
}
```

Comment: and what about this varian: String[] values = { "A1", "B1", "C1", "5" , "string"}; To separate into three arrays?

Comment: I presume that for your example `"string"` it means "strings with no numbers". In this case, create a new function `StringContainsNoNumbers`, just as in `StringContainsNumbersOnly` but i in this case `return Regex.IsMatch(inputString, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$");`. Then you use `String[] noNumbers = (from x in values where StringContainsNoNumbers(x) select x).ToArray();` and you are good to go.

Comment: As you can see, the whole point consists in doing "select x where x matches the desired case". So you can just google "c# string contains no numbers" or whatever your desired case is, and plug it in your "select" statement.

Answer (score 1):

If your definition of a cell reference is a string starting with a letter you can do something like:

```
List<string> cellReferences = new List<string>();
List<string> digits = new List<string>();
String[] values  = {"A1","B1","C1","5"};

foreach(string val in values)
{
  if(Char.IsLetter(val[0]))
    cellReferences.Add(val);
  else
    digits.Add(val);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple linq is enough...

```
String[] values = { "A1", "B1", "C1", "5" };

var groups = values.ToLookup(s => s.All(char.IsDigit));

String[] b = groups[false].ToArray();
String[] c = groups[true].ToArray();
```

**EDIT**

And for your tri-state case

> and what about this varian: String[] values = { "A1", "B1", "C1", "5" , "string"}; To separate into three arrays?

```
String[] values = { "A1", "B1", "C1", "5", "string" };

var groups = values.ToLookup(s => s.All(char.IsDigit) ? 1 : s.All(char.IsLetter) ? -1 : 0);

String[] alldigit = groups[1].ToArray();
String[] allLetter= groups[-1].ToArray();
String[] mixed    = groups[0].ToArray();
```